# What is the Maximum Type Depth?

Tags: apex

I saw this question posted as an answer, but no one seems to have asked it since.

> What is the maximum number of levels classes can inherit?

In other words, what are the maximum `N` and `M` such that the following will still compile?

```
public virtual class C1 { }
public virtual class C2 extends C1 { }
// ...
public virtual class CN extends CM { }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't in the docs. Nice find!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Maximum Type Depth` appears to be 10. That means the maximum `N` is 11 and the maximum `M` is 10. Attempts to compile the following class will illustrate:

```
virtual class C1 {}
virtual class C2 extends C1 {}
virtual class C3 extends C2 {}
virtual class C4 extends C3 {}
virtual class C5 extends C4 {}
virtual class C6 extends C5 {}
virtual class C7 extends C6 {}
virtual class C8 extends C7 {}
virtual class C9 extends C8 {}
virtual class C10 extends C9 {}
virtual class C11 extends C10 {}
virtual class C12 extends C11 {}
```

The above will throw the following compile error:

> Line: 12, Column: 7
>   C12: Maximum type depth exceeded: 10